# Имплементация интерфейса с generic type

Tags: java, generics, интерфейс

Помогите с реализацией интерфейса. Допустим у нас есть интерфейс

```
public interface Sorter<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    void sort(List<T> list);
}
```

и я хочу создать класс, который будет реализовывать этот интерфейс используя genec types. Я пробовала так:

```
public class SorterImpl<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Sorter<T > {
    public void sort(List<T> list){
        boolean erijuht1 = true; 
        boolean erijuht2 = true; 
        for(int a=0; a<list.size()-1; a++){
            if(list.get(a) > list.get(a+1)){
                erijuht1 = false;
            }
            if(list.get(a) < list.get(a+1)){ 
                erijuht2 = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что последний класс не хочет сравнивать объекты между собой.
Как мне реализовать данный интерфейс так, что бы класс был и с generic type, и мог сравнивать объекты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не можете в данной функции сравнивать два объекта таким образом, так как не понятно какой из них считать большим, а какой меньшим *(и равным)*. `list.get()` возвращает Вам объект класса `T`, наследуемый от `Comparable<T>`. Значит мы можем использовать вызывать все методы этого класса, а в данном случае `compareTo` *(возвращает 1,0 или -1)*. Осталось добавить код для перемены мест в случае если "больший" имеет меньший индекс. Вот что получилось:

```
public class SorterImpl<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Sorter<T> {
    public void sort(List<T> list) {
//        boolean erijuht1 = true;
//        boolean erijuht2 = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size() - 1; j++)
            for (int a = 0; a < list.size() - j - 1; a++) {
                if (list.get(a).compareTo(list.get(a + 1)) > 0) {
//                    erijuht1 = false;
                } else {
//                    erijuht2 = false;
                    T temp = list.get(a + 1);
                    list.set(a + 1, list.get(a));
                    list.set(a, temp);
                }
            }
    }
//Тестируем
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(2);
                add(3);
                add(5);
                add(8);
                add(2);
            }
        };
        SorterImpl s = new SorterImpl();
        s.sort(ar);
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(ar.get(i).toString() + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

Результат:

> 8 5 3 2 2

Comment: А зачем нужны переменные `erijuht1` и `erijuht2`?

Comment: @privod старался минимально править код автора. Закоментировал те строчки, который в данном ответе не нужны. Спасибо.